# How to link Python3.7 to VS2019 C++ Project

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to use a python module in a C++ project I'm developing in VS2019 and seem unable to link it. I've added my `Python37-32/Includes` directory to the `Additional Include Directories`, added my `Python37-32/Libs` folder to my `Additional Library Directories` and `Python37-32/Libs` to my `Additional Dependencies` yet still get an error. The error is `LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Python37-32\libs.obj'`. I've tried numerous fixes including : deleting configurations and removing the libs directory from `Additional Dependencies` however this often results in numerous undefined Python functions which obviously indicate the library isn't being linked.

How would I go about linking this correctly?

Comment: You should add library files to `Additional Dependencies`, not directories

Comment: As I said in the question, I've added `C:/Python37-32/Libs` to both `Additional Dependencies` and `Additional Include Directories` and am getting this error. When I remove it from `Additional Library Directories` and only have it in `Additional Dependencies` I still get this error. Could you elaborate if that's what you intended?

Comment: you should not add `C:/Python37-32/Libs` to `Additional Dependencies`, you should list **library files** there. Linker will search for the files listed among `Additional Library Directories`

Comment: So for instance, python37.lib in Additional Dependencies? This still gives me a slightly different error that `python37.lib` could not be opened.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. My configuration was correct without `Additional Dependencies` however my version of Python being referenced was 32-bit on a 64-bit build.